# what does the "nice priority" mean about iostat command's %nice

Tags: linux, nice, iostat

I googled the iostat command's man manual about the %nice. In the [explanation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) of the value of %nice there is a phrase about nice priority. I can not understand the meaning about it, can someone explain it?

The complete comment in the man page is as follows.

> %nice
>
> Show the percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the user level with nice priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means processes that have been started with the `nice` command, or have called `nice`/`setpriority` to lower their priority below the standard one. (`nice` was the name of the system call in older unixes as well, it's been replaced by `setpriority` now. The command name is still the same).

See the manual page or documentation for /proc/stat, for example, http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt.

Or, try it yourself (on an otherwise unloaded system that belongs to you!). Open 2 terminals. In the 1st, type

```
$ perl -e 'print "$$\n"; for (;;){}'
```

and remember the pid, then in the second

```
$ ps -l -p <pid>
$ iostat -c 1 5
```

Then, stop the process in the 1st terminal, and restart it with lower priority:

```
$ nice -1 perl -e 'print "$$\n"; for (;;){}'
```

Output, on my system:
(first time)

```
$ perl -e 'print "$$\n"; for (;;){}'
22482
$ ps -l -p 22482
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 R  1000 22482 22443 99  80   0 -  4279 -      pts/1    00:00:16 perl
$ iostat -c 1 5
...
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
         100.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

(With nice)

```
$ nice -1 perl -e 'print "$$\n"; for (;;){}'
22666
$ ps -l -p 22666
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 R  1000 22666 22443 99  81   1 -  4279 -      pts/1    00:00:06 perl
$ iostat  -c 1 5
...
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00  100.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

The `nice -1` command causes the NI column to increase by one; at the same time, the 100% CPU usage (that is caused by the perl command) moves from %user to %nice.

Comment: so does you mean that any porcess run at priority below zero? Do you have any canonical link about it?

Comment: Added some examples. Be careful with "priority below zero", a process that gets less CPU is "nice" to other processes, i.e. has a HIGHER nice value. So, a process will get more CPU if it has a LOWER number in the NI column.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong undersatanding and your example is very comprehensive. Thanks.